# Do Jekyll Themes Receive Security Updates?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-theme

I'm setting up a personal website on GitHub Pages using Jekyll.  I'm using the Cayman theme.  I used [this documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/) to override some of the theme's defaults.  The documentation said:

> making copies of theme files will prevent you from receiving any theme updates on those files.

I'm OK with not receiving feature updates but I'm not OK with missing out on security updates.  Do Jekyll themes ever receive security updates?  A Google search didn't turn up anything helpful.

I don't think they do (since a Jekyll site is a static site) but I would like some input/confirmation from someone more knowledgable than myself.

Comment: If you build and deploy your Jekyll site once, the site will be using a point in time snapshot of the Cayman theme.  Assuming you are using `gem` to get the Cayman theme, pulling the latest version of the theme via `gem`, and building/republishing your Jekyll website, then you will stay up to date with the latest code changes from Cayman every time you rebuild/republish.

You can also "Watch Releases Only" to get GitHub notifications for when a new Cayman theme releases so you know to rebuild your website. https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman